# Add Image to JOptionPane

Tags: java, image, swing, joptionpane, messagedialog

I'm wondering How To Add Image To MessageDialog Box.  I tried the code below and the image was nowhere to be found

```
else if(button == B){
String text = "blahblahblahblahblah";
    JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(text);

textArea.setColumns(30);
textArea.setLineWrap( true );
textArea.setWrapStyleWord( true );
textArea.setSize(textArea.getPreferredSize().width, 1);
Font font = new Font("Verdana", Font.BOLD, 12);
textArea.setFont(font);
textArea.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(
null, textArea, "Border States", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);

image2 = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("borderstates.jpg"));
  label2 = new JLabel(image2);
  add(label2);
```

Comment: What is a MessageDialogBox?

Comment: From the showMessageDialog method

Comment: Thanks everyone for the help! I figured it out using Mel and MadProgrammer's advice!

Answer (score 20):

`JOptionPane` is a very flexible API.

Your first port of call should be the [Java API Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html) and the [Java Trails](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/), specific [How to use Dialogs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html)

[image][image]

```
public class TestOptionPane04 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(TestOptionPane04.class.getResource("/earth.png"));
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(
                        null,
                        "Hello world",
                        "Hello", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE,
                        icon);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(
                        null,
                        new JLabel("Hello world", icon, JLabel.LEFT),
                        "Hello", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice globe.  That is the nicest GUI version of 'Hello world' I've seen. :)

Answer (score 5):

What is a MessageDialogBox? If you mean add an image to a JOptionPane, there are method overloads that accept an Icon, and so this is one way to solve this. Another is to create a JPanel or JLabel with your image and other components and then display this in the JOptionPane.

Comment: I used a JLabel as you can see in the code, but how do I put it in JOptionPane.                                                             Note: I'm new to Java and programming in general

Comment: +1, there is also HTML formatting for displaying multiple images & resizing them at run-time.

Answer (score 5):

From the javadoc on JOptionPane:

```
public static void showMessageDialog(Component parentComponent,
                                     Object message,
                                     String title,
                                     int messageType,
                                     Icon icon)
                          throws HeadlessException
```

Just make an `Icon` of your image and add it as a 5th parameter.

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, textArea, "Border States", 
    JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, image2);
```

Don't forget to define image2 before you use it (move the line up)