# How to display an image from a website in a JOptionPane?

Tags: java, selenium

I use selenium to test a webpage . I want to display an **image from that webpage** on a JOption pane  . How can I do this ? Here is the code

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver() ; 

driver.get(http://.........com)  ;

WebElement imageElement = driver.findElement(By.id("imageID")) ; 

JOptionPane.showInputDialog // ?
```

How to include this image from a website to a JOption Pane ? DO I need to download it first ?

Comment: check answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13963392/add-image-to-joptionpane

Comment: @CHEBURASHKA `ImageIcon` can use a URL so perfect for what you want (generally though you dont want to rely on an external address for resources)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First we must find the element.  Note that the element *must* be the `<img>` element.

```
WebElement imageElement = driver.findElement(By.id("imageID"));
```

Next, we get the url of the image within that element:

```
String imagePath = imageElement.getAttribute("src");
```

We convert it into a URL:

```
URL imageUrl = URL(imagePath);
```

Then we read it into an image:

```
Image image = ImageIO.read(imageUrl);
```

Finally, we put it in an JOptionPane:

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "message", "title", JOptionPane.OK_OPTION, new ImageIcon(image));
```

Now, please note that I have split the code into separate lines because I want you to actually understand what the code is doing.  None of the steps are particularly hard, and would have definitely been possible with some google searches.

Answer (score 1):

```
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("c://photo.jpg");
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "message", "title", JOptionPane.OK_OPTION, icon);
```

Comment: +1 Thank you . THe question asked about how to include an image from a webpage . `<img id="imageID" src=          " ` NOT `C: .. . ` THe tag is `selenium` .