# Unable to set custom image in showMessageDialog() icon in Java lang

Tags: java, user-interface

[image]

I tried to set a custom image in the `showMessageDialog()` icon.

```java
public class MessageDialog1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

            ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon("luffy.png");
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Wrong Password Fardeen!", "Custom Icon", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, img);

    }
}
```

but it just shows plain icon in the message dialog

Update: solved it by adding `getResource()` method
[image]

updated code:

```java
 ImageIcon img =  new ImageIcon(MessageDialog1.class.getResource("luffy.png"));
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Wrong Password Fardeen!", "Custom Icon", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, img);
```

Comment: Maybe something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13963392/add-image-to-joptionpane/13963645#13963645)?

Comment: Duplicate of [Add Image to JOptionPane](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13963392/add-image-to-joptionpane)